# Converting xtable of Markdown Equations to Word or .rtf

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc

I've created tables in Rmarkdown using xtable.

I need to convert them to either `.doc` or `.rtf` in order to submit to a journal.

I can successfully convert to `.html` and `.pdf` but when I convert these formats to `.doc` or `.rtf`, the nice equation formatting disappears.

I've tried opening the files in word and converting to `.rtf`. Is there a way to do this without re-doing the tables entirely? I am fairly new to Markdown and Pandoc.

Here is the reproducible code.

````
---
title: ''
output:
  html_document:
    df_print: paged
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    keep_tex: yes
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:
- \usepackage{lineno}
- \linenumbers
---

```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
library(xtable)
Parameter <- c("T","V","$i$")

Definition <- c("Temperature (C)","Velocity (cm/s)","Prey class within $I$ 1 mm bins")

Method <- c("Field data","Field data","$EC = SC + MC$","$NEI = GEI - EC$")

Reference <-c("","", [1,2]")
table1_df <- cbind.data.frame(Parameter, Definition,Method,Reference)
table1 <- xtable(table1_df, include.rownames=FALSE, caption="This should be a pretty table")
print(table1, comment=FALSE, include.rownames=FALSE, caption.placement="top",size="\\fontsize{9pt}{10pt}\\selectfont", sanitize.text.function=function(x){x}, type="html")
```
````